# Issue when filtering with UISearchResults

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uisearchbar

So I have a list of friends coming from the API and I've tried to implement also the search functionality. So far, so good, the filtering is good, but my first section is actually a button that sends me to another VC and it 's getting irritating that that cell always appears when I try to search through the friend list. Actually, i want it to be hidden when I search for friends.

I added some pictures to make it more clear [image: this is how first the VC shows]
[image]
[image]

As can be seen the third picture shows clearly the problem.

My code looks like.

```
var friendList = [Conversations]()
var filteredFriends = [Conversations]()

 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return friendList.count + 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if isFiltering() {
        return filteredFriends.count
    }
    if section == 0 {
        return 1
    } else if section == 1 {
        return friendList.count
    }
    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewGroupConversationCell") as! NewGroupConversationTableViewCell
        return cell
    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewConversationCell") as! NewConversationTableViewCell
        var friendList: Conversations

        if isFiltering() {
            friendList = filteredFriends[indexPath.row]

        } else {
            friendList = self.friendList[indexPath.row]
        }

        cell.populate(friendList)
        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}

    func searchBarIsEmpty() -> Bool {
    // Returns true if the text is empty or nil
    return searchController.searchBar.text?.isEmpty ?? true
}

func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    filteredFriends = friendList.filter({( friend : Conversations) -> Bool in
        return (friend.name?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))!
    })

    mainTableView.reloadData()
}

func isFiltering() -> Bool {
    return searchController.isActive && !searchBarIsEmpty()
}

extension NewConversationViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
// MARK: - UISearchResultsUpdating Delegate
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!)
}
```

Pls tell me if you need more explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your the numberOfSection is equal to number of friends, that's why you have the number of action button equals to number of friends, try

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2 // your button, and your friend list
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        if isFiltering() {
            return 0 // hide button
        }
        return 1
    } else if section == 1 {
        if isFiltering() {
            return filteredFriends.count
        }
        return friendList.count
    }
    return 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide section 0 when you are using filtered list.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2 // Default 2 sections
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        if isFiltering() {
            return 0
        }
        return 1
    } else {
        return friendList.count
    }
    return 0
}
```